# Robocopy, copy unchanged files on interval

Tags: robocopy

I want robocopy to copy a file that will never change to a directory over and over again. The file will change in the destination directory and need to be overwritten with the original every 5 minutes.

currently using the following command, which looks for 1 change.

```
C:\>robocopy C:\ C:\new config.sdf /MOT:5
```

Comment: Just create a Windows Task Scheduler job to run and copy every 5 min.

Comment: Can you create an answer for this @Filburt

Comment: I'd rather not, since it doesn't answer your question as such but proposes a different solution. If you feel it needs this answer you could describe your own implementation using my suggested workaround.